# Which mobile company delivers Android system updates the fastest?

Tags: updates, android-versions

Basically, I am an Android developer. I am looking for a new Android mobile phone.

Could you recommend the mobile company which first publishes an update of Android system? I am tipping at HTC, but you may have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Buy a Nexus S device directly from Google. They will be the fastest at updating to the latest firmware. And they will always ship with Stock Android. Everyone else is Way behind. most are behind because they add customizations to android and have to make their changes, then they have to go through the google approval process. Not to mention then having to go through the carriers testing process for deployment.

Comment: Good point.  The latest flagship device is always the best bet, not a particular company.

Comment: Does Google have any official devices with a hardware QWERTY?

Comment: no, the only one they had w/ a hardware keyboard was the ADP1 (HTC Dream / G1)

Comment: Is this available to non-US countries/citizens?

Comment: @Ryan, damn, I find touchscreen keyboards *so* frustrating to use :-(

Answer (score 0):

LG promises but fails to deliver, Samsung comes up with the updates pretty quick. Tries to cover all phones that might show an improvement with new version.

Comment: Samsung? Their US versions of Galaxy S that came out ~6 months ago was released with Eclair, and just got Froyo recently. No official Gingerbread builds yet AFAIK.

Comment: @Ryan, so you **do not** recommend Samsung Nexus S? Just Google Nexus S?

Comment: Samsung is one of the better ones in India.

Comment: the nexus S is manufactured by samsung, for google.